# How to defer function execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Say I have a Javascript API which consists of two functions, the first of which does some async work before calling a callback:

```
function api1(args, callback) {
   some_async_op(function() {
       callback()
   })
}
function api2(arg) {
   ...
}
```

It is important that api2 is only allowed to do its work after api1 has completed its async work and called its callback. However it so happens that the client calls to these apis are generally synchronous, i.e.

```
api1(arg, function() { ... })
...
api2(arg)
```

How may `api2()` be implemented so that it cannot run until `api1()` has completed? Obviously the `api2()` call could be placed in the callback passed to `api1()` but I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Why not have api1 return a promise, and then your users can chain the secondary function call off of that promise?

Comment: Is the case that once api1() executes, api2() can execute whenever it wants? Or, does api1() always have to be re-executed prior to api2()?

Comment: Are these API calls being done in a browser or Node.js?

Comment: If clients are making calls to your API synchronously when they shouldn't be, either your API needs fixing or your documentation does (or perhaps both)

Comment: call `api2()` inside the callback of `api1()`

Comment: aka "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" - Doctor replies "don't do that".

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned the complicating factor is that the client of this API is C++/WASM where async programming is not quite as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that async programming is so ubiquitous in javascript that you could expect users to simply use a promise returned by `api1`, or have `api2` only available as a method on an object returned by `api1` asynchronously.

I hesitate to post this because it feels hacky,but maybe it will inspire something useful. You could do something where `api1` and `api2` share a promise. This forces the main functionality of `api2` into a `then()` on the promise. This can get ugly if you need to do more than one independent call of the pair of functions.

```js
const some_async_op = cb => setTimeout(cb, 500)

let resolver, p

function api1(cb) {
  if (!p) p = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolver = resolve
  })
  some_async_op(() => {
    cb()
    resolver()
  })
}

function api2() {
  (p || (p = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolver = resolve
  })))
  .then(() => console.log('api 2 done'))
}

// call api2 first
api2()
// sometime later call api1
setTimeout(() => api1(() => console.log('api1 callback fired'), 600))
```